# Angular-Mapping value from NgRx selector into an object to be returned as an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I want to return an observable (line 6) as DataObject. Line 9 is listening to store changes, so when there is a store change - lines 10,11,12 execute but not before store change right? Or Will it get the existing value in the store and execute the block (lines 10,11,12).
But if store hasnt changed yet, will line 14 wait until line 10,11,12 execute or will it return line 14 as empty object?  **What can I do if I want to listen to changes -> map the data from store into DataObject and return it as observable, not before that?**

```js
class DataObject {
  propA: string = '';
  propB: string = '';
  propC: SecondDataObject;
}

getDataModel(): Observable<DataObject> {
  let data = new DataObject();
  this.store.pipe(select(appState)).subscribe((val) => {
    const data = new DataObject();
    data.propA = val.propA;
    data.propB = val.propB;
    data.propC = val.propC;
  });
  return of(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a new observable like below :-

```
getDataModel():Observable<DataObject>()
         {
           let data = new DataObject();
           return new Observable((observer) => {
              this.store.pipe(select(appState)).subscribe((val)=>{
                data.propA = val.propA;
                data.propB = val.propB;
                data.propC = val.propC;
                observer.next(data);
                observer.complete();
              }));
           });     
         }
```

Comment: could i also answer what?

Comment: also @Amers solution looks better if you don't want to create observable urself for some other usecase.

Comment: Hi Aakash, thanks a lot for your answer. Could you also answer - If the store isnt updated/changed yet, will it get the existing value(or default value) from the store and execute the block (lines 10,11,12)? Or is it executed only when there is a NEXT change in the store?

Comment: it will execute with current value, not on next changes, if you want all changes, remove observer.complete and unsubscribe in ngondestroy of component where you are using getDataModel.

Comment: Ok so initially the selector gets the value (current value-whatever is there in the store, and initially it is the default state value) and keeps on listening to any other changes. On any change, it will subscribe to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that without subscribing to the `selector`, just by using the [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator and retuning the `Observable` itself, like the following:

```js
getDataModel(): Observable<DataObject> {
  return this.store.pipe(select(appState)).pipe(
    map((val) => {
      const data = new DataObject();
      data.propA = val.propA;
      data.propB = val.propB;
      data.propC = val.propC;
      return data;
    })
  );
}
```